# Why do I need to use '-P' when I grep a list?

Tags: unix, grep

I am using the -P option to grep a list of phone numbers.  My results are excellent with this option, but the list is not returned without it.  The [grep man page](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) says using -P will 'interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression'.  Since I don't know Perl and am just learning grep and regex this isn't very meaningful to me.

Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: sample data, grep targets AND good and bad output samples are required to make a meaningful comment. Please edit your question to include these. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 sets of regular expressions that could be used by `grep`:

- [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) — basic regular expressions
- [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tab_09_04) — extended regular expressions
- [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) — [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)-compatible regular expressions

Some of the concepts are the same between all these.  For example, a character-class such as `[a-z]` or `[^0-9]` is the same in all of them.  On the other hand, the meaning of `(` vs `\(`, or whether `|` or `+` or `|` has a special significance, depends on the class of regular expressions.

This is a big topic; too big to cover easily in an SO answer.  To find out more, look to Jeff Freidl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) book, and at the documentation for the difference sets of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `-P` option `grep` interprets the pattern as a basic regular expression, and there are big differences between them, for example with metacharacters like `.`, `?` or `|`. You will have to adapt your regexp.

Comment: So now I'm learning about metacharacters, too.  Thanks a bunch for the help.